# Accessing Grails ActiveMQ from Remote Machine

Tags: java, grails, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I am new to JMS stuff.. I read the JMS and ActiveMQ plugins documentation but still not clear with it .

I am trying to build a system where a Grail app hosted on machine A with ActiveMQ embedded in it should be capable of sending messages. And another Grails app hosted on Machine B with just the JMS plugin should be able to receive messages and respond to it.

After reading the documentation I created a grails App on machine A where controller  sends the message to service on Machine A and it displays the message on Console. Now I am trying to implement a service with similar behavior on Machine B.

After configuration on Machine B , my resource.groovy looks like this:

```
 1
 2  import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory
 3 import org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory
 4 beans = {
 5
 6     jmsConnectionFactory(SingleConnectionFactory) {
 7         targetConnectionFactory = { ActiveMQConnectionFactory cf ->
 8                                         brokerURL = 'vm://machineA.mydomain.com'
 9                                   }
 10         }
 11 }
```

And the service on Machine A and B look like this:

```
1 package replicationsiteapp
2
3 import grails.plugin.jms.*
4
5 class OnNotificationService {
6
7
8             boolean transactional = false
9             static exposes = ['jms']
10             static destination = "topic.notify"
11             boolean isTopic = true
12
13
14             @Subscriber(topic = "topic.notify")
15             def onTopicMessage(it){
16                 
17                 println " YOU GOT MESSAGE FROM : $it"
18             }
19
24 }
25
```

Controller on Machine A:

```
   package hello
   class NotificationController {

   def index() {
    def message = "Hi, this is a Hello World with JMS & ActiveMQ, " + new Date()
    sendTopicJMSMessage("topic.notify",message)
render message
   }
}
```

Machine A:
Grails 2.1 on Unix with plugins installed (ActiveMQ and JMS)

Machine B:
Grails 2.1 on Unix with plugins installed (JMS)

Current Issue:

When message is sent from Controller on Machine A
Service on Machine A displays message in console but Machine B doesnot

Expected:
Machine B should also receive the messages

Answer (score 1):

Your broker URL refers to an in VM resource:

brokerURL = 'vm://machineA.mydomain.com'

Please review the Connection page in activemq:

http://activemq.apache.org/configuring-transports.html

This is the one that will most likely help you: http://activemq.apache.org/connection-configuration-uri.html

Comment: Thanks John: But I  tried  'tcp://machineA.mydomain.com:61616?jms.useAsyncSend=true'   but even that did not work...will try to see if http works

Comment: on your server machineA, did you enable a listener?

Comment: Hey John..... The OnNotificationService is the listener. I have implemented exactly same listener on both Machine A and Machine B. When I send message from machine A. I see messages printed on console of Machine A but not on console of Machine B.